# Proving that $(1+m)^{-1/n} + (1+n)^{-1/m} \ge 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I need to prove the following inequality:

$$
(1+m)^{-1/n} + (1+n)^{-1/m} \ge 1
$$
for every natural $m,n$.

there shouldn't be any complicated math here, as this question if from a first semester calculus course in university, and it's a homework about limits and inequalities, i have no idea how to start.
i tried a few different ways but it's pretty hopeless.

Comment: I'm sure that I've already seen this question on Math.SE...

Comment: I tried searching first, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac1{a}+\dfrac1{b}
\ge 1$
iff
$a+b \ge ab$
iff
$ab-a-b \le 0$
iff
$ab-a-b+1 \le 1$
iff
$(a-1)(b-1) \le 1$.

If
$a = (1+m)^{1/n}$
and
$b = (1+n)^{1/m}$,
$a \le 1+m/n$
and
$b \le 1+n/m$
so
$(a-1)(b-1)
\le (m/n)(n/m)
= 1
$.

To show that
$(1+x)^{1/n}
\le 1+x/n$,
raise both sides
to the $n^{th}$ power
and use Bernoulli's inequality
($(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$
for $x \ge 0$ and $n \ge 1$).

Comment: Thanks for the help, we didn't learn bernoulli's inequality though, is there another way to show this part?

Comment: This is a very useful inequality and easily proved by induction: if $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$ then $(1+x)^{n+1} = (1+x)(1+x)^n \ge (1+x)(1+nx) = 1+(n+1)x+nx^2 \ge 1+(n+1)x$.