# Basic root inequality proof: sum of 2 roots above 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, roots

this is the first time I upload to this site. I got this in my differential and integral mathematics class for physicists:

for $n,m∈\mathbb{N}  $  prove:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}}\ge 1$$

I'm pretty early in the course so I'd preffer a simple answer with use of mainy basic inequalities (the triangle inequality, bernoulis inequality, other simple and basic subjects).

Comment: Where does this come from? It's appeared here a few time recently.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065587/proving-that-1m-1-n-1n-1-m-ge-1